# Cannot get ASP dynamically created control using FindControl

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have created many dynamic controls. I would now like to find those controls and review their contents on postback before proceeding with the database write.

Controls created as follows:

```
  For i As Integer = 0 To numberOfSplitItems
    Dim combo As New RadComboBox()
    combo.ID = "MonthSpliCombo" & i
    'Items then added to the combobox
    monthDIV.Controls.Add(combo)
    splitdiv.Controls.Add(MonthDIV)
    PanelActualSplit.Controls.Add(splitdiv)
  Next
```

This is working 100% and my controls are all added where they should be and are working.
I can find all these controls in javascript no problem.

```
  Protected Sub processSplitMonthsBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
     For i As Integer = 1 to numberOfSplitItems
      Dim monthBox As New RadComboBox
      Try
        monthBox = DirectCast(PanelActualSplit.FindControl("MonthSpliCombo" & i), RadComboBox)
        MsgBox(monthBox.ClientID)
      Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
      End Try
     Next
  End Sub
```

Error it keeps showing:  System.NullReferenceException: Object not set to an instance of an object.

I have adjusted as follows to try determine my error:
  taken out 'DirectCast'
  tried to use TryCast
  Dim monthBox as RadComboBox - leave out the 'As New'

I have tried multiple controls, but I cannot seem to get the control saved into the monthBox control so that I can start my validation.

Please could you assist.

Comment: I had the same issue and kept coming across posts saying that you would need to 'register' the control with the page in order for vb to find it during postback, since it was loaded on the page after the page load event fired. Never could get it to work so I ended up putting several invisible controls on the page and just revealed them as they were needed. Verbose, but it works...

Comment: That really sucks....it doesn't make sense, if the server has created it, it must surely be able to find it again? I hear what you are saying, but there must be some work around with ajax of some sort...will keep digging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite simple.

Upon each postback the controls are refreshed, thus losing the controls that were dynamically created on the last postback.
Viewstate of the controls needs to be remembered and thus "recreated" on the next postback.

Move your procedure which created the controls into it's own sub and add the following overrides to your code.

```
  Protected Overrides Function SaveViewState() As Object
    Dim viewState = New Object(1) {}       

    viewState(0) = Integer.Parse(numberOfSplitItems)

    viewState(1) = MyBase.SaveViewState()
    Return viewState
End Function

Protected Overrides Sub LoadViewState(savedState As Object)        
    If TypeOf savedState Is Object() AndAlso DirectCast(savedState, Object()).Length = 2 Then
        Dim viewState = DirectCast(savedState, Object())
        Dim count = Integer.Parse(viewState(0).ToString())
        yourAddcontrolsProceduresHere(count)
        MyBase.LoadViewState(viewState(1))
    Else
        MyBase.LoadViewState(savedState)
    End If
End Sub
```

That will solve the issue and reload the controls on your postback thus allowing the server to access find them and you will no longer have the Null reference exception.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `PanelActualSplit.FindControl` you should use a function similar to this:

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control ctl, string id) {
    if (!ctl.HasControls())
        return null;
    Control res = null;
    foreach(Control c in ctl.Controls) {
        if (c.ID == id) {
            res = c;
            break;
        } else {
            res = FindControlRecursive(c, id);
            if (res != null)
                break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

in this way:

```
RadComboBox monthBox = (Table)FindControlRecursive(PanelActualSplit, "MonthSpliCombo" & i);
```

And you will find your control for sure.

Comment: I have tried my best to convert that to VB...and alas, it's still not working. NullReference exception is still coming up.